# Is there any way that bold IntelliJ vertical indent guides?

Tags: intellij-idea

I wonder how to bold IntelliJ vertical indent guides.

The result which I found recommend this way.

Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General -> Vertical indent guide.

But I can't find this menu.

How can I get it?

Comment: Can you show in editor when you want to customize?  `But I can't find this menu.` What do you have there? I see it: https://monosnap.com/file/X2snWVZRvbqElWpfZcBPNffNdpZEPB

Comment: I finally find it! Thank you for your help :)